# Calculating a range of dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

So I'm trying to figure out a sql syntax that would allow me to create a date range based on a table that breaks everything into months.  This typically would be easy except for a small caveat where "skip" months could occur.  In which case we need to take those into account for creating ranges.

So for example:

[image]

The date range is the column I want to create - and for piece A it's actually pretty straight forward but piece B (highlighted) -I'm unsure how to break up the date ranges if there is a "break" in the months

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Minus 1 for posting screenshots of data.

Answer (score 3):

This is a gaps and islands problem -- but with months.  So, just subtract a sequence number from the start dates.  For months that are sequential, this will be constant and can be used for defining each period of contiguous months.

Normally, I would aggregate the data just down to the ranges:

```
select col1, min(col2), max(col2)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1, dateadd(month, - seqnum, col2);
```

It turns out that the same idea works with window functions, so:

```
select col1, col2,
       min(col2) over (partition by col1, dateadd(month, - seqnum, col2)) as range_start,
       max(col2) over (partition by col1, dateadd(month, - seqnum, col2)) as range_start
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that I've put the range ends in separate columns.  That is how I would want the results.  You can of course convert them to strings and format them however you would like.